# python csv module strip lines before parsing

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7

I have a plain text file:

```
    2 jordyt
    2 dawder
    2 LOL12345
    2 2251084185
    2 123456789
    2 123456
    1 warcraft
    1 tripp88
```

after parsing it via `python's csv` module , i have:

```
with open(filename,'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=' ')
    for row in reader:
        print row

['', '', '', '', '', '', '2', 'jordyt']
['', '', '', '', '', '', '2', 'dawder']
['', '', '', '', '', '', '2', 'LOL12345']
['', '', '', '', '', '', '2', '2251084185']
['', '', '', '', '', '', '2', '123456789']
['', '', '', '', '', '', '2', '123456']
['', '', '', '', '', '', '1', 'warcraft']
['', '', '', '', '', '', '1', 'tripp88']
```

EDIT 1:

I expect the output like this:

```
['2', 'jordyt']
['2', 'dawder']
['2', 'LOL12345']
.
.
.
```

i can fix this problem with a custom pre-processor. but, those files are so big, and its not good to read them twice.

my question is: how can i tell the csv module to strip the lines before parsing it?

Comment: What exactly should the output be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to provide the [`skipinitialspace`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.skipinitialspace) parameter:

```
with open(filename,'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=' ',skipinitialspace=True)
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

Comment: simply using `csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=' ',skipinitialspace=True)`, also works fine.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary - Thanks!  Didn't realize you could provide the dialect options directly, but I see it now in the docs.  Edited my answer to use that instead.

Answer (score 4):

If your delimiter is a space, then I would be tempted to not use the CSV module (if you know you've not got quoted fields with spaces):

This takes advantage of the nature of `split()` or `split(None)` dealing with consecutive delimiters nicely.

```
with open(filename,'r') as csvfile:
    for row in csvfile:
        print row.split()
```

Or, if you need to deal with it and use the CSV module, just create a generator over your input file and pass that to the reader):

```
with open(filename,'r') as csvfile:
    stripped = (row.strip() for row in csvfile)
    reader = csv.reader(stripped,delimiter=' ')
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

Comment: I like your first example, but I think you needed to go one step further and use split on the lines, since FJ seems to want the words separated.

Comment: @Lee-Man: Actually, I think he meant `split` *instead of* `strip`.

Comment: Actually - yes I did :( - updated - thanks for the catch guys

Comment: yes, it works. but the F.J's answer is exactly what i want.minimum code changes, and using pre-created logics in built-in modules.instead of reconstructing them.

Answer (score 1):

I question your use of csv in this case, since split() will do what you want.

```
with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
    for row in csvfile:
        words = row.split()
        print words
```

prints (for your data):

```
['2', 'jordyt']
['2', 'dawder']
['2', 'LOL12345']
['2', '2251084185']
['2', '123456789']
['2', '123456']
['1', 'warcraft']
['1', 'tripp88']
```

Comment: hey man, why is csv needed in this case? I'm just not seeing it. Perhaps the data you supplied is not representative of the data you really have to parse, but given the data you supplied, csv is kind of overkill.

Comment: absolutely you are true, but just for training purpose i want to do this by csv module. all of this thread created to do this via csv module. you cannot ignore it !

Comment: @pylover, that was not clear to me from your original question but understood now.